# readlines will always block the caller

Tags: python

I'm reading *Programming Python* by Mark Lutz, and I came across this bit:

> For pipe objects, the effect of iterators may be even more useful
>   than simply avoiding loading the entire result into memory all at
>   once: readlines will always block the caller until the spawned program
>   is completely finished, whereas the iterator might not.

What does this mean?

Comment: What happens when you call a ReadLine function on stdin?

Comment: What I think it means is that if you call readlines you fetch the entire item (file) in memory and your program "blocks" until the entirety of the item is fetched. On the contrary, if you use iterators you fetch one thing (/one line) at a time so you don't bring the whole thing in memory. A side effect og this is that you don't block the caller for very long time since you are fetching smaller chunks at a time.

Answer (score 1):

if you consider `subprocess.Popen` as an example. If you call a command that outputs a lot of data  to `subprocess.PIPE` then calling `proc.stdout.readlines()` will  wait until the command completely finishes.

Where if you were to use `iter` with `for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,"")`, you would see the output in real time and also avoid having to store all the output in memory.

If you had to process each line of the output it would make more sense to process line by line as the input came in which using `iter` allows you to do as opposed blocking until the command terminates using `readlines`.